# Use less spaghetti-code in my

Tags: javascript, css

I try to make a small demo where I can drag and enlarge circles.

I have the functionality (thanks to stackoverflow) to make that work for one circle and I could now go ahead and copypaste that code and just edit the functions/variables names. But I don't think this is the right approach.

My code looks like that for the styleing and the css-variables:

```js
var circle_1 = document.querySelector("#circle_1");
var resizer_1 = document.querySelector("#resizer_1");
var size_1 = document.body.style.getPropertyValue("--size_1");
var circle_2 = document.querySelector("#circle_2");
var resizer_2 = document.querySelector("#resizer_2");
var size_2 = document.body.style.getPropertyValue("--size_2");

// Function(s) to grow the circle having terrible spaghettis ahead
function growCircle_1() {
  var size_1 = window.getComputedStyle(circle_1).getPropertyValue("--size_1");
  var size_1_n = size_1 * 2;
  circle_1.style.setProperty("--size_1", size_1_n);
}
function growCircle_2() {
  var size_2 = window.getComputedStyle(circle_2).getPropertyValue("--size_2");
  var size_2_n = size_2 * 2;
  circle_1.style.setProperty("--size_2", size_2_n);
}

// Event listener
resizer_1.addEventListener("click", growCircle_1, false);
resizer_2.addEventListener("click", growCircle_2, false);

// Drag-Zone
$( function() {
  $( "#circle_1" ).draggable();
  $( "#circle_2" ).draggable();
});
```

```css
:root {
  --size_1: 50;
  --size_2: 50;
}

body {
  margin: 100px;
}

#circle_1 {
  width: calc(var(--size_1, 50px) * 1px);
  height: calc(var(--size_1, 50px) * 1px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#circle_2 {
  width: calc(var(--size_2, 50px) * 1px);
  height: calc(var(--size_2, 50px) * 1px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: cyan;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.7.2/dragula.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.7.2/dragula.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="circle_1" draggable="true">

  <span id="resizer_1">Group 1</span>
</div>
<div id="circle_2" draggable="true">
  <span id="resizer_2">Group 2</span>
</div>
```

You can see it right here: https://codepen.io/daiaiai/pen/QQXrGz
How would I set up the code to have a cleaner code without being too advanced ( so I can still as a clear beginner understand what's done there)
for multiple circles #circle_3 #circle_4....

Comment: Code review questions should be asked on Code Review, not Stack Overflow. This question is primarily opinion-based and thus off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can see you are using jquery in your code,

```
$( function() {
    $( "#circle_1" ).draggable();
  $( "#circle_2" ).draggable();
  } );
```

using jquery it is much easier to do.
we can use the [jqueryUi resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/)

your Html

```
<div class="circle ui-widget-content" draggable="true">
<div class="circle ui-widget-content" draggable="true">
<div class="circle ui-widget-content" draggable="true">
<div class="circle ui-widget-content" draggable="true">
```

css

```
.circle{
   width: 50px
   height: 50px
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin-top: 20px;
   background-color: pink;
   opacity: 0.7;
   display: inline-block;
   transition: 0.3s;
}
```

js

```
$( function() {
   $( ".circle" ).draggable();
   $( ".circle" ).resizable({
      aspectRatio: 1 / 1  /*to keep the width same as the height*/
   });
});
```

**Important** in order for resizable to work you need to use 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

and that is all you need you will have a draggable and resizable circles

Comment: Oh yeah, that's really way easier :) Thanks a lot. I leave vanilla js to the developers :)

Answer (score 0):

use class in javascript :) Its not complete solution. You need to add more stuff like styling event listeners and so on but its doable. Try it out

```js
// Drag-Zone
$( function() {
  $( "#circle_1" ).draggable();
  $( "#circle_2" ).draggable();
  $( "#circle_3" ).draggable();
  
});

class Circle {
  constructor(id,name,size, color,opacity) {
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
    this.opacity = opacity;
    
  }
  get Add(){
    return this.html();
  }
  html(){
    let circleHtml='<div style="width=" id="circle_'+this.id+'" draggable="true"><span id="resizer_'+this.id+'">'+this.name+'<span></div>';
    return circleHtml;
  }
}
const circle1 = new Circle(1,"Group1","50px","red","0.7");
$(document.body).append(circle1.Add);
const circle2 = new Circle(2,"Group2","50px","red","0.7");
$(document.body).append(circle2.Add);
```

```css
:root {
  --size_1: 50;
  --size_2: 50;
}

body {
  margin: 100px;
}

#circle_1 {
  width: calc(var(--size_1, 50px) * 1px);
  height: calc(var(--size_1, 50px) * 1px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#circle_2 {
  width: calc(var(--size_2, 50px) * 1px);
  height: calc(var(--size_2, 50px) * 1px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: cyan;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.7.2/dragula.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.7.2/dragula.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: I got the point. Makes sense. But within your solution: Does it resize for you?